# Sloane or the Charlatan?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

After spending some time on Kadara you will get to meet the leader of the outpost, an outcast called Sloane, and the leader of the Collective. You're asked to make a decision that chooses one of these as the leader of the Kadara outpost.

What are the impacts of choosing either Sloane or the Collective to lead Kadara Port?

Comment: I sided with the collective. Other than a few thank you gestures from people on the nexus and collective associates on other worlds. I haven't seen anything that would impact the story... Yet.

Comment: Sloane turns up during the final mission if you save her

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real impacts in this game are as follows:

- Outcast NPCs in Kadara Port are replaced with Collective NPCs.
- Unconfirmed, but I am no longer attacked by Collective enemies, and am always attacked by outcast enemies.

Spoilers relating to the end of the game:

> If you save Sloane, she will assist you during the final mission by using her shotgun to kill enemies. If you save the Charlatan, they will provide you with sniper fire cover during the final mission

The long term affects are likely to play out over the coming sequels.

Comment: I assume it would affect a romance with the Charlatan as well.

Comment: I'd imagine it will also affect the next game, even if you wanted to kill the Charlatan, you only graze him, so they kept him alive for some reason, maybe he'll become a team member and cause the most awkward reunion ever!